# How to separate Facilities package from Apache OFBiz?

Tags: ofbiz

I am beginner for apache ofbiz framework. I want to know how to separate their demo packages for our purpose. Is there any reference please kind to be inform about that.
 Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with separating the demo package?

For a better experience ask such questions in the user ml of the Apache OFBiz project, see here: https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html